# GAE email me errors

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Can GAE be configured to bust me an email when there's an error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best you can do is to have in your `main` function some code like...:

```
try:
  ...normal body of your main goes here...
except:
  from google.appengine.api import mail
  import sys

  mail.send_mail(sender="Your GAE App <yourappname@example.com>",
              to="You <bobobobo@example.com>",
              subject="GAE App error",
              body="""
Your App Engine app raised an exception:
  %s
""" % sys.exc_info()[:2])
```

(of course, you can do better formatting on the exception information, etc, etc).

Comment: Just don't be surprised when you end up with a few hundred e-mails per minute ;-) If your load is high, store exceptions in a database, and e-mail them (or a summary) periodically with a cron job.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of using GAE to send an email.  You could build on this example to catch exceptions and send an email to yourself....

http://www.fishbonecloud.com/2010/11/automated-email-using-google-app-engine.html